# How do I fix LNK1256 ALINK 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified, from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

I am trying to compile a Visual Studio C++ project with /CLR, and I am getting the error:

> **Error    LNK1256 ALINK operation failed (80070002) : The system cannot find the file specified.**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this means the linker cannot find the file(s) specified in the 'Assembly Link Resource' field of the project properties, passed to the linker via the /ASSEMBLYLINKRESOURCE option.